# Azure DevOps: add commit message with multiple lines to new pull request

Tags: azure-devops

When I create a new pull request on Azure DevOps and i click on the "Add commit messages" button, only the first line of each commit message is added to the description field.

Since my commit messages have multiple lines, I'd like the entire commit message to be added to the description field.

Has anybody experienced this behavior and is there a way to fix it?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

> Has anybody experienced this behavior and is there a way to fix it?

I am afraid there is no such way to add commit messages with **multiple lines** to a new pull request at this moment.

There is user voice about it, you could vote and add your comments for this feedback. When there are enough communities vote and add comments for this feedback, the product team member will take this feedback seriously.

[Support multiline commit messages](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/t/support-multiline-commit-messages/626988)